# Routing between pfSense Subnets and IPSec VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, ipsec, pfsense

I have a pfSense Router, which is the endpoint of a site-to-site IPSec VPN.
In the pfSense the main LAN Interface is 10.0.2.1/24 and it has a virtual IP 10.0.125.1/24
The IPSec Phase 2 connects the 10.172.0.0/16 (from the other side) to the 10.0.125.1/24 network.
Now I want to connect to an ip from the other side, but from an ip in the 10.0.2.0/24 network

So the desired connection is 10.0.2.27 to 10.172.0.119
I tried to add the 10.0.125.1 as a gateway in the pfSense and route all traffic to the other network over it, when i did so i could ping the other side from the pfSense host but not from the 10.0.2.0/24 network.
I tried to add Outbound NAT, but that didn´t helped either.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Network]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some time, but here is the answer:
Edit the P2 in pfSense, set Local Network to: `Network 10.0.2.0 /24` (the network where the clients actually reside)
and set NAT/BINAT translation to: `Network 10.0.125.0 /24`

So the VPN tunnel will be established between the remote Network and 10.0.125.0 /24
but
the clients from 10.0.2.0 /24 can connect and are nated via this option.

I only tested this if the connection is initalized from my side, I don´t know if the remote site can establish the connection

Comment: you really should have two phase2 entries, simplifies configuration, debugging, troubleshooting even if the functionality really were the same.

Answer (score 6):

Duplicate your existing P2 (click the + to the right of it), change local from 10.0.2.0/24, leaving same 10.172.0.0/16 remote. Do the same, flipping local and remote, on "other router." Then you'll be able to communicate between.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem is that I don´t have access on the other side, so my question is if i can nat that traffic through the pfSense
But outbound nat didn´t work (or i made it wrong)

Comment: If you only need egress traffic to that VPN, yes. Add another P2 only on your side, make the NAT subnet 10.0.2.0/24 and local 10.0.125.0/24

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one P2. you should have two phase2 entries on both sides one per block.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Did you read the other answers?